# UE4 Can I load .umap into packaged standalone?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I need to load on start .umap files created after packaging standalone version of my app. The problem is that .umap need to be cooked (even when I uncheck Pak flag). How can I solve that?

What I want to accomplish is that to build standalone app. Let designers to create some .umap level files in Unreal Editor. And finally to be able to start my app with new .umap level.

I see 2 possible ways:

Find some plugin or tool which can separately cook .umap file and add it to packaged project. Does such a plugin exists?

Build standalone project without cooking (I don't need to redistribute the project, it's tool for internal use). Is it possible?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [UAssetManager](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest//INT/Engine/Basics/AssetsAndPackages/AssetManagement/index.html) class, which could be used for loading UE4 assets at runtime. However, I can't promise you it will load entire map for you, i've never used this mechanism at my own.